# How to create a path for a labyrinth with physics body in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, macos, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, cgpath

I want to create a labyrinth for my SpriteKit Game, but I have problems setting up the correct physics body. Take a look at this example:

[image: example]

blue : CGPath

green : labyrinth (CGPath linewidth=10)

red : physics body I want to create

I tried to draw the labyrinth with CGPath and SKShapeNode, but how can I set up the physics body for the inner bounds of my labyrinth?

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 38, 266);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 37, 23);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 127, 22);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 127, 184);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 273, 185);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 273, 98);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 274, 184);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 127, 184);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 127, 23);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 364, 23);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 364, 266);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
SKShapeNode *labyrinth = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:path];
labyrinth = [SKColor greenColor];
labyrinth.lineWidth = 10;
[self addChild:labyrinth];
```

.

```
labyrinth.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:path];
```

does not work. I need an option to include the line width of my path for the physics body.

Any suggestions or other options to implement a labyrinth like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @primaryartemis! with your suggestion i created the following code:

```
        for (int i=0; i< [points_array count]-1; i++) {
              // first point
              CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(points_array[i].x, points_array[i].y);
              // second point                  
              CGPoint p2 = CGPointMake(points_array[i+1].x, points_array[i+1].y);
              // midpoint
              CGPoint p3 = CGPointMake(p1.x-p2.x, p1.y-p2.y);

              float angle = atanf(p3.y/p3.x);
              NSInteger length = sqrt(p3.x*p3.x + p3.y*p3.y);

              SKSpriteNode *frameElement = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor yellowColor] size:CGSizeMake(length+10, 10)];
              frameElement.zRotation = angle;
              frameElement.position = CGPointMake(p1.x-p3.x/2, p1.y-p3.y/2);

              frameElement.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:frameElement.size];
              [self addChild:frameElement];
        }
```

it works. Here is a sample output:
(red is the physics body, blue is the midpoint)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered building the labyrinth out of rects?

Each labyrinth wall could be a rectangular shape or sprite node then you would use [bodyWithRectangleOfSize:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithRectangleOfSize:) to give each shape/sprite node a physics body that is the same size as themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't spend hours translating your code, just create a body with the final image from your SKShapeNode.

Your node must be in the view since you would be using a SKView method named textureFromNode: as follow.

```
if(labyrinth.scene.view)
{
    SKTexture *texture = [labyrinth.scene.view textureFromNode: labyrinth];

    labyrinth.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:texture alphaThreshold:0.0 size:texture.size];
    labyrinth.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
}
```

Comment: so SKShapeNode labyrinth can be a png image? How?